# How can I clip a shapefile or KML layer file within ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, clip

Please see attached images for reference. What I'm trying to do is edit segment lines so that the polygons are not multiple. To do this I want to connect the lines so it is one continuous line for the outlining boundary.

See images - there is [image: the original with the inner polygons]. Then there is [image: another image of what I want it to look like after clipping.]

I tried to clip the segment line - but that tool option is greyed out, even in edit mode. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was under the impression that KML is read-only in ArcGis... what license level do you have? What tool is it that is greyed out?

Comment: I have a shapefile version of this also. I have the basic license I believe. The clipping tool is greyed out.

Comment: It is a basic license type - is that why the clipping functionality and the line segment tools are greyed out?

Comment: quite possibly, reshape should be available though. When you install ArcGis desktop all the tools are installed however tools are disabled if they require a higher license than the one being consumed... if you're on a floating license perhaps you could elevate to Standard or preferably Advanced to gain access to much better tools; with an advanced license you could use 'Feature to Polygon' to fill in the holes and then select & Editor::Merge to remove holes and/or 'Polygon to Line' to get the boundaries, edit and then 'feature to polygon' to make them back into polygons.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work for shapefile/GDB featureclass but I doubt it will work for a KML. If you want to edit kml, convert to a shapefile/GDB FC first.

Start editing. Select a feature that you want to merge internal holes. Select the "Reshape Features Tool" on the Editor toolbar. Draw a polygon connecting the selected feature to the feature to merge it with.

[image]

[image]

Select the Cut Polygons Tool. Draw line where you want to cut the polygon. Delete the cut section.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I want my image to look like the second one, which involves clipping. Notice on the second image it is white and it is cut through. Will your answer solve that? Maybe I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: A clearer question would lead to a clearer answer... have you tried Editor::Clip? It needs one (no more than one) polygon selected then can either remove everything under or keep everything under the selected polygon... A workflow of creating a polygon, Editor::Clip then delete the created polygon might be closer to what you're after.

Comment: @Kristen see edit